# android httppost why use $_REQUEST and not $_POST in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, android, mysql, httpclient, http-post

I've been going through tutorials and reading up on how to POST android data into MySQL, and I've only seen people use $_REQUEST['something'] when passing variables. Why is it only $_REQUEST? and not $_POST? is it the same thing? I'm still learning all the goodies between both android development and php,

If someone can kindly explain, that'll be awesome,

Thanks!

Comment: by using $_POST only we can get POST variables and $_GET only we can get GET variables.when we use $_REQUEST can get variables GET & POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Krishna pretty much answered it in the comments above:

> By using `$_POST` we can only get POST variables and `$_GET` we can only 
>   get GET variables. When we use `$_REQUEST` can get variables in GET & POST.

Comment: While it is some sort of meta-answer, if you're going to post it as an answer, please provide.. well.. an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would never do that.  Using `_REQUEST` is popular for some reason, but your requests should always be using `_GET` for retrieval or `_POST` for storage (and perhaps other methods as well -- it depends).  You should never need to say "this value may be from either a post or get request and is valid in both of those cases, so we need to use `_REQUEST`."  If that's what's happening, there are problems.

People also tend to forget that `_REQUEST` includes `_COOKIE` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use post method for sending data then you must have to use $_POST variable to get posted data
vice versa if you use get method for sending data you must have to use $_GET variable to get posted dat

$_REQUEST is use to get posted data in both case whetever method either post or get you use for posting data.
It is beneficial to use $_REQUEST for getting data